# Kinect, Matlab and picture saving with Skeleton

Tags: matlab, kinect

I working on one project with Matlab and Kinect sensor. I have function for a taking a pictures for a training from Kinect sensor. The problem is that I want to save pictures with Skeleton over picture in data set such as shown in video. it only save picture without skeleton.

I think that error is somewhere about this line:

```
imwrite(img, fullfile(fileLocation,sprintf('Picture%d.png', nImages)));
```

and instead of img must be something else.

Thank you in advance.

My code is:

```
function Sample(MainFolderName, ObjectFolderName,delay)


if nargin < 3
    delay = 0.1;
end

videoC = videoinput('kinect',1);
videoDepth = videoinput('kinect',2);


%% Skeleton info
triggerconfig(videoDepth,'manual');
videoDepth.FramesPerTrigger=1;
videoDepth.Triggerrepeat=inf;
set(getselectedsource(videoDepth),'TrackingMode','Skeleton')

start(videoDepth);
for i=1:100
    trigger(videoDepth);
    [depthMap,~,depthMetaData]=getdata(videoDepth);
    imshow(depthMap,[0 4000]);
end

%%
skeletonJoint=depthMetaData.JointImageIndices(:,:,depthMetaData.IsSkeletonTracked);
imshow(depthMap,[0 4000]);
hold on; plot(skeletonJoint(:,1),skeletonJoint(:,2),'*');
stop(videoDepth);

%% Draw and track skeleton
triggerconfig(videoC,'manual');
videoC.FramesPerTrigger=1;
videoC.Triggerrepeat=inf;
start(videoDepth);
start(videoC);

%% Create folder with label name
fileLocation = fullfile(MainFolderName,ObjectFolderName);
if ~exist(ObjectFolderName,'file')
   mkdir(fileLocation)
end

%% Take pictures
nImages = 1;
fig = figure('Name','Pictures for training','NumberTitle','off');
ax = axes('Parent',fig);
try
    while ishandle(fig)
        pause(delay);
        trigger(videoC);
        trigger(videoDepth);
%         [frameDataColor] = getdata(videoUlaz);
          img = getdata(videoC);
%         image = frameDataColor(:,:);
    [depthMap,~,depthMetaData]=getdata(videoDepth);
    if sum(depthMetaData.IsSkeletonTracked)>0
        skeletonJoints=depthMetaData.JointImageIndices(:,:,depthMetaData.IsSkeletonTracked);
          util_skeletonViewer(skeletonJoints,img,1);
         imwrite(img, fullfile(fileLocation,sprintf('Picture%d.png', nImages)));
         title(sprintf('Number: %3.0f',nImages))
         nImages = nImages+1;  
%     else
%     imshow(img);
    end
    end
    stop(videoC);
    stop(videoDepth);
    imaqreset;
catch
    imaqreset;
end
%% Display Info
nImages = size(ls(fullfile(fileLocation,'*.png')),1);
disp('---------Training images!---------')
disp(['Name: ',ObjectFolderName])
disp(['Nubmer: ',num2str(nImages)])
disp(['Location: ',fullfile(pwd,fileLocation)])
```

Comment: Please, add a sample picture of the output you would like to obtain

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change this line:

```
imwrite(img, fullfile(fileLocation,sprintf('Picture%d.png', nImages)));
```

with these:

```
frame = getframe;
imwrite(frame.cdata, fullfile(fileLocation,sprintf('Picture%d.png', nImages)));
```

N.B.: I have assumed that your `util_skeletonViewer` is [this one](http://www.depi.itchihuahua.edu.mx/irobledo/cursos/taller_kinect_matlab/util_skeletonViewer.m).